# sql server: Unique constraint generates unique key and unique index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unique-constraint, unique-key, unique-index

I’ve got 2 tables:

attCatAppSet, attCatAppSet_translation

On both tables I’ve applied a unique constraint on 2 columns (that are not Primary Keys), so that column-pair values can't be duplicated.

```
GO
ALTER TABLE attCatAppSet
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_category_id_setOrder 
UNIQUE(category_id, setOrder)
GO


GO
ALTER TABLE attCatAppSet_translation
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_siteLanguage_id_attCatAppSet_id 
UNIQUE(siteLanguage_id, attCatAppSet_id)
GO
```

Result: looking at the object explorer I get 2 different implementations of my commands.
On table attCatAppSet, there is a unique index constraint.
On table attCatAppSet_translation, there is a unique index and unique key constraint.

[image]

Same thing shows if I call:

```
GO
sp_helpIndex attCatAppSet
GO
sp_helpIndex attCatAppSet_translation
```

[image]

- How come I've got 2 different implementations of the query?
- What is the difference between the 2 results?

Comment: At first blush, siteLanguage_id has a foreign key constraint while setOrder does not.

Comment: both constraints have at least a FK column, but this shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constraint in the table `attCatAppSet` contains `setOrder` field, that **is not a foreign key**. So your foreign key in `attCatAppSet` is just `category_id` - and it is also displayed as a foreign key. But your constraint `UNIQUE(category_id, setOrder)` requires combined unique index of `category_id` and `setOrder` - and so this index was created and is displayed as a normal index (not as a foreign key).

Foreign keys are used to define relations between tables. It seems that you have already created the relations before creating theese constraints. (e.g. you have already defined relation between `attCatAppSet_translation` and `siteLanguage` tables etc.)

The constraint `attCatAppSet_translation` contains two foreign keys, so it is displayed as a key that has following meaning: `attCatAppSet_translation` table contains only unique combinations of `siteLanguage` and `attCatAppSet`.

Only two combined unique indexes were created. **The both indexes created by SQL Server are functionally equivalent, only they are displayed with different icons.** It is only about how database model is documented within SQL Server Management Studio.

Further information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1562/should-i-use-a-unique-constraint-or-a-unique-index-in-sql-server/).

> UNIQUE constraints are part of the ANSI SQL definition and defining
>   UNIQUE constraints is part of defining a database's logical design.
>
> From a performance standpoint, UNIQUE constraints and unique indexes
>   are effectively the same to the query optimizer and you will not see
>   any performance benefit to using one vs the other.

Comment: Thus the "same" result can be achived with: CREATE UNIQUE  INDEX [UQ_category_id_setOrder] ON [dbo].[attCatAppSet] (
[category_id]
, [setOrder]
) ?

Comment: @Luther, a foreign key may be bound to a primary key, unique constraint, or unique index.  Any of these that have the same columns as the foreign key can be used but you have no direct control over which is used if you have redundant indexes.  See http://www.dbdelta.com/secrets-of-foreign-key-index-binding/

Comment: @VDohnal and Dan Guzman - SQL Server MVP, (I know it's redundant) thanks.